# How to know the users connected in an Ubuntu 18.04 / xrdp

Tags: 18.04, xrdp, user-management

I have an Ubuntu 18.04 that allows xrdp connections.

Users normally connect via an rdp client, but I would like to know who is connected at any given time.

I tried `who` , `w` , etc. but those commands never show the xrdp users.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: The already answered and linked answer is useful to find the connected users.
If instead of using Xvnc on the xrdp connection you use Xorg, the command could be: `ps -ef | grep Xorg`

Answer (score 0):

Open the terminal and run this command:

```
{ echo "user pid Xdisplay port"; { ps -ef | awk '/Xvnc :[[:digit:]]+/ {print $1,$2,$9}' | while read tu tpid tvnc; do sudo netstat -tlpn | awk -v "tpid=${tpid}" '$0 ~ tpid {print $4;}' | sed -r -e 's/^.*://;' -e "s/^/${tu} ${tpid} ${tvnc} /;" ; done ; } | sort -k3 ; } | column -c4 -t
```

Comment: Thanks a lot karel for the suggestion.
I am using Xorg instead Xvnc inside the xrdp connection so I'm trying to modify your command ... unsuccessfully till now